# Transferring Microsoft CRM data

Tags: migration, backup-restoration, crm

My boss has asked me to transfer data from the current Microsoft CRM 4.0 server to a new one. I myself haven't used CRM at all. I've done some research and come across various ways to import data from different sources. These methods include using CSV files and Data Maps. This seems very cumbersome and unnecessary since the data is already in a CRM. Would someone please direct to some guides for full/partial data transfer from this current CRM to a new one?

Comment: There isn't a generic <LineOfBusinessApp1> to <LineOfBusinessApp2> data transfer method.  I suggest looking at the documentation/support for LOBApp2 first and if that doesn't provide the answer then the sales dept can usually provide a quote for doing a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a LOT of caveats, you're best off familiarizing yourself with the [implementation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1ceb5e01-de9f-48c0-8ce2-51633ebf4714&displaylang=en) - not fun reading, but it's not as bad as it looks.  Just a matter of paring that mountain of data down to the few steps that apply to your situation.